# Javascript Silly Question: if-statement syntax

Tags: javascript

There being a ' ; ' after one and not the other. I was wondering if there was a difference or additional functionality between these 2 if statements?

```
func(x){  // with a ; at end
    if (false){
        throw new Error('blah');
    };
}

func(x){  // without a ; at end
    if (false){
        throw new Error('blah');
    }
}
```

Comment: A semi-colon ends a statement. A statement can be empty. So you can even do `};;;;;;;;;;;;` and it will still be OK.

Comment: What is funt - intentional typo ???

Comment: haha was a typo, thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference.

You don't need a `;` after a statement block. If you add one, it's just terminating an empty statement, which doesn't do anything.

The first version is probably a typo, it's not normal to put a `;` there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no differences or additional functionality between the 2 statements

Semicolons are optional in javascript, the interpreter will insert a semicolon at the end of a statement if needed.

In other programming languages like C, the semicolon denotes to the compiler the end of one instruction and the beginning of the next.